# No enabled compatible agents for this build configuration. TeamCity on Ubuntu

Tags: .net, linux, ubuntu, continuous-integration, teamcity

I try to deploy my .Net Core project to the Ubuntu server using TeamCity. TeamCity automatically detected build steps after connecting my BitBucket repository to TeamCity. 
but then I click the "run" button in the upper right corner, a message appears:

> Warning: No enabled compatible agents for this build configuration. Please register a build agent or tweak build configuration requirements.

[image]

This is my build agent:
[image]

I am new to CI and Ubuntu, so I would be grateful to the detailed answer.
I think the problem may be here, but how to fix it? 
[image]

This is my build steps. The problem exists even if I disable first step.
[image]

**UPDATE** If i disable first and second steps, I see this message in agent:
[image]

Comment: Disable or delete step 1 and 2. You don't need them since this is .net core and you are doing restore in step 3, and build in step 4.

Comment: @Peska Yes I tried to do it but it didn’t help

Comment: @Peska After disabling the first and second steps, I see a new message

Comment: Do you have .net sdk installed on agent machine? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-package-manager-ubuntu-1910 After installation you will need to restart agent.

Comment: @Peska I follow all steps to install net sdk. When I click to "reboot agent machine" the following message is displayed: "Can not reboot: this agent is installed on the TeamCity Server host" :(

Comment: @Peska I reboot my agent machine. All works fine now! Thank you so much!!